# What is the difference in meaning between when using "the risk" and "risks" in the following sentence?

Tags: definite-articles

"Habitual physical activity reduces the risk of hypertension and diabetes."
"Habitual physical activity reduces risks of hypertension and diabetes."

What is the difference in meaning ?

Answer (score 1):

> Habitual physical activity reduces the risk of hypertension and diabetes.

This suggests to me that there is a risk that I might get hypertension and diabetes (that is, I might get both of them together!), and that physical activity can help me reduce that risk.

> Habitual physical activity reduces risks of hypertension and diabetes.

This suggests to me that there are separate risk factors for hypertension and diabetes, and that physical activity will help me reduce my risk of each of them.

The difference is only very subtle, and in practice most people would probably read them as meaning much the same thing.

Comment: This is the distinction I interpret as well, but I'm not sure the author really intends that the first implies that you'd get both conditions. He most likely meant _and/or_, but omitted _or_ because it's clumsy and the intent is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I read the singular as implying high-correlation between the two diseases and the lack of exercise.

The plural is explicit in separating hypertension from diabetes in sharing a common stressor.